# Expressions in Tim Minchin's "Storm"

Tags: meaning, expressions

Can you help me with these expressions from [Tim Minchin's *Storm*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB_htqDCP-s)? There will be some obscenities—sorry for those; I am just interested in their meaning.

- "I confess a pigeonhole starts to form" [1:10]
- "diplomacy dike" [2:55]
- "What are we - fucking two" [4:55]
- "Horton heard a who" [4:55]
- "Blow your hippy noodle" [7:12]

Comment: psmears: thanks for adding the timestamps. I will do it in future questions.

Comment: Great question, I myself googled most of those after I become Tim's huge fun.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- "I confess a pigeonhole starts to form": This is referring to the third definition of *pigeonhole* [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pigeonhole), "a neat category which usually fails to reflect actual complexities". He is saying that he is beginning, in his mind, to ascribe to her the characteristics of a particular stereotype (the details of which become apparent later on). The term comes from the use in offices of shelves with compartments for different types of form - so there will be a pigeonhole for form 43A, and another for form 66C; the term is also used in UK offices for what I believe in the US would be called a mailbox. Of course this in turn comes from its physical resemblance to the original meaning, "a hole for pigeons to live in".
- "diplomacy dike": He is using the word "dike" (spelt "dyke" in the UK - that is not an error in the subtitling!) in sense 2b [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dike): a barrier or dam to hold something undesirable back. By "diplomacy dike" he means his diplomatic self-restraint, which generally serves to keep his tongue from voicing his insulting thoughts, and in this case is holding back a barrage of abuse (that comes out later in the poem).
- "What are we - fucking two": He means "two years old". The word "fucking" here has no semantic content, it merely serves to emphasise his anger and frustration.
- "Horton heard a who" This is a reference to the name of a [childrens' book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horton_Hears_a_Who!), continuing in the theme of comparing the girl to a two-year-old. This book is particularly apt, because the main character claims the existence of phenomena that nobody else has observed, and is ridiculed for doing so, yet stands up for it.
- "Blow your hippy noodle": This combines two idioms - "noodle" as a [slang term for "head"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noodle), and the phrase "blow (someone's) head" (or "blow (someone's) mind"), meaning (roughly) to massively surprise them / hugely challenge their expectations and beliefs (the image is that the concept will actually make their head explode). The word ["hippy" (often spelt "hippie")](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hippy?show=1&t=1302358450) is his description of her worldview, and by extension her head.

Comment: Fantastic answer, good work. (+1)

Comment: I would agree with Karl, this is an excellent answer.  However I would make one small correction.  The name of the book is "Horton Hears A Who" not "Horton Heard A Who".

Comment: @Kevin: Good spot - I meant to say "is a reference to", I've edited to correct. Thanks!